Audacity python detect if I'm at end of track?
Anyone know how I can use scripting to get the exact position of my cursor? such as 02:23:33.
I've been looking through the stuff on this page about scripting commands:
https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/scripting_reference.html
Right now I'm using SelNextClip to select clips, in my image I have the middle clip selected. But lets say I have the last clip of a track selected, how can I tell that im at the end of the track?

